# How to automate background width in CSS

Tags: css, background, width

I want to add a 45 degree striped bar at the right on my page titles.

```
<div class="page-main-title">My Title</div>
<div class="title-bar"> <img /></div>

.page-main-title{
float: left;
font-family: 'Proxima Nova Regular';
font-size: 48px;
color: #767676;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-bottom:32px;
margin-top: 16px;
margin-right: 12px;
}

.title-bar{
float: left;
height: 32px;
width: 200px;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 25%, #dcdbd9 25%, #dcdbd9 50%, white 50%, white 75%, #dcdbd9 75%, #dcdbd9);
background-size: 20px 20px;
margin-top:8px;
}
```

Since the titles of the various pages of my website don't contain the same number of characters, I would like to find a way in CSS to fill all the white space at the right of my page titles with the bar. So far, the bar will show up if a fix the width (*ie: 200px*). However, it would be great if the width of the bar could automatically be adjusted to the remaining space at the right of the title, no matter how many characters it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below an alternative, without using float property. You create the "stripe" container full width, append the title container in with a white background.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjhL96ne/

HTML

```
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="page-main-title">My Title</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="page-main-title">This a Title</div>
</div>

<br/>
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="page-main-title">This a long Title</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-main-title {
    font-family:'Proxima Nova Regular';
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #767676;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 12px;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
}
.title-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 25%, #dcdbd9 25%, #dcdbd9 50%, white 50%, white 75%, #dcdbd9 75%, #dcdbd9);
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

That's how it would look :

[image]
**EDIT :**

Please check the following fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/yjhL96ne/2/

Using absolute position to display "stripes" under title with a smaller height.

Comment: I am not looking to have a bar as a "background image" under my title text text but at the right of the title.

Comment: Right I understand that but because the title's background color is white the visual effect is the same or I don't quite get what you are looking for?

Comment: I would want something like this for any title length:
http://s1.postimg.org/iaa8hr6v3/image.jpg
The bar would fill all the remaining white space at the right of the title no matter what the title length is.

Comment: Ok, slightly different. Let me edit the JSfiddle to match that.